# Get all facebook comments and likes with Rfacebook?

Tags: r, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the rfacebook package to get all the comments/likes on a set of posts. The code is working fine, but I'm stuck now with the maximum number of comments and likes to return (*n*). I need the complete set of comments/likes and sometimes that *n* is very very big. Is there a way to make multiple requests to get all the comments/likes in smaller sets, kindda like pagination?

right now I'm just changing the max value but I'd rather do something cleaner...

basic code i'm using to get the comments/likes:

```
post <- getPost(post_id, token, n = 1000, likes = TRUE, comments = TRUE)
```

Comment: How many posts do you want in a variable?

Comment: The idea was something like n=200, make more requests but get smaller responses.